# Delete duplicate data takes more than 10 hours MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MYSQL. I want to delete duplicate data on my tables but it takes a whole day still running like it is in an infinity loop.
Here is a script I run to clear all duplicates data on tables that contains like 5000 data combine.

```
DELETE en1
     , cm1
     , reg1
     , yr1
     , cmod1
     , mocat1
     , sem1
     , ex1
     , pen1
     , exdet1
     , excat1
     , exres1 
  FROM student_class_enrollment en1
     , acad_class_course_module cm1
     , student_registration_id reg1
     , college_academic_years yr1
     , acad_course_module cmod1
     , acad_class_course_module_category mocat1
     , semester sem1
     , acad_class_course_module_exam ex1
     , acad_course_module_penalty pen1
     , acad_class_course_module_exam_detail exdet1
     , acad_class_exam_category excat1
     , acad_class_course_module_exam_result exres1
  JOIN student_class_enrollment en2
     , acad_class_course_module cm2
     , student_registration_id reg2
     , college_academic_years yr2
     , acad_course_module cmod2
     , acad_class_course_module_category mocat2
     , semester sem2
     , acad_class_course_module_exam ex2
     , acad_course_module_penalty pen2
     , acad_class_course_module_exam_detail exdet2
     , acad_class_exam_category excat2
     , acad_class_course_module_exam_result exres2
 WHERE en1.id < en2.id 
   and cm1.id < cm2.id 
   and reg1.id < reg2.id 
   and yr1.id < yr2.id 
   and cmod1.id < cmod2.id 
   and mocat1.id < mocat2.id 
   and sem1.id < sem2.id  
   and ex1.id < ex2.id 
   and pen1.id < pen2.id 
   and exdet1.id < exdet2.id 
   and excat1.id < excat2.id 
   and exres1.id < exres2.id
   and en1.id = en2.id 
   and en1.student_id = en2.student_id 
   and cmod1.code = cmod2.code 
   and exres1.raw_mark = exres2.raw_mark 
   and excat1.cat_code = excat2.cat_code 
   and exdet1.ex_weight = exdet2.ex_weight
```

I don't know where I'm going wrong please I need help to speed up this task. Thanks

Comment: It's often quicker to create a new table, retaining just those rows you want to keep. And we stopped writing queries this way circa 1992.

Comment: thanks for rearranging my script. Can you clarify how I may accomplish that. Do I have to create a new table for every table I want to delete

Comment: That's would be a reasonable approach.

Comment: Only 2 tables, not 1 table per column!